# How to select rows that match substring in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have a table "players" with these entries:

```
id: 1
name: "player1"
owner_id: 1 

id: 2
name: "player2"
owner_id: 2 

id: 3
name: "player3"
owner_id: 1
```

I also have a table "users", like this:

```
id: 1   
name: "user1"

id: 2   
name: "user2"
```

Now, there is a table named "messages" with entries like this:

```
id: 1
content: "content1" 
tag: "/players/1/messages"

id: 2
content: "content2" 
tag: "/players/2/messages"
```

What I need is to get a list from table "players" and also include the field "content" from table "messages".

The problem is that I need for example only get rows for a specific user. So if I want to list all the rows for user_id = 1, it becomes difficult to fetch the rows from the table "messages". As this table doesnt have any relationship.

My idea was to have some kind of regex or substr-function. Basically, getting a list for user_id = 1 accoridng to the entered data above, I would have this result:

```
id: 1
name: "player1"
owner_id: 1
content: "content1" 

id: 3
name: "player3"
owner_id: 1 
content: null
```

Actually, the id=3 above can be exluded as I am only interested in rows from "players" that also have an entry in "messages".

Is regex or substr a good way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to use 
regexp_replace

and also casting it to integer, as it was a string containing an ID.